# command prompt help, show specific files

Tags: file, batch-file, for-loop, command, command-prompt

Need your help 
I need create a batch file (command prompt) to 
    ⁃   Show a list of folders and sub folders 
    ⁃   within them are exe files 
    ⁃   Only show the 2 most up to date exe files
    ⁃   display specific folders not all

And export information in a txt file

I'm using XP if that helps

update

I have the below commands

first one works and orders by most recent file, but doesn't give me time and date

second shows time and date but doesn't order by most recent

---

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set j=0
Echo Test
echo\
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir C:\test\ /o-n-d /b') DO (
    echo %%i
    set /A j=j+1
    if !j! geq 2 (
        goto :end1
    )
)

:end1
```

---

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set j=0
echo\
Echo Test
echo\
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('forfiles /p C:\testmove /s  /m *.* /C "cmd /c echo @file @fdate @ftime" ') DO (
    echo %%i
    set /A j=j+1
    if !j! geq 2 (
        goto :end2
    )
)

:end2 

pause
```

Comment: More precise information is needed about the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "lastdir="
(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /s /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.exe" '
  ) DO (
  IF "%%~dpa" neq "!lastdir!" (
   SET "lastdir=%%~dpa"
   SET /a count=0
   FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /s /b /a-d /o:d "%%~dpa\*.exe"') DO IF !count! lss 2 (
    SET /a count+=1
    ECHO %%~ti %%~fi
   )
  )
 )
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

Produces newfile.txt. You would need to set your required directory name in `sourcedir`. I showed the data as date/time fullfilename because fullfilename is of variable-length whereas date and time are fixed. Might have been easier if you'd shown us the format you expect - saves guesswork and revisions.

---

To show the two most recently modified files, change `.../b /a-d /o:d "%%~...` to `.../b /a-d /o:-d "%%~...` (note `-` between the `o:` and `d`)

Comment: Thank you Magoo, just one question this outputs the last modified file is there a way to reverse this , to show the two most recent (modified) file's.

Answer (score 0):

Uses Robocopy to show the two latest modified `.exe` files in the current folder tree
It also displays the UTC date and time of the two files.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "folder=%cd%"
set c=0
for /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%a in (
    'robocopy "%folder%" "%folder%" "*.exe" /s /is /nocopy /nc /ns /ts /fp /np /ndl /njh /njs /xjd /r:0 /w:0 /l ^| sort /r '
) do echo "%%a %%b" - "%%c" & set /a c+=1 & if !c! EQU 2 goto :done
:done
pause
```

Comment: Great this seems to work too however I cant seem to see the time and date just the file name and path

Comment: Do you need the date and time in local time, or is UTC date and time ok?  You see Robocopy operates and displays in UTC date/time.  I modified the code above slightly to display the info for you to see how it appears.

Comment: Foxidrive - Wonderful work , the new code works perfectly , thank you all for your help :)